# Как найти максимальное значение в модели данных

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, модель-данных

Нужно вытащить максимальное значение answer1.Data[].Id из модели данных

Сама модель

```
public class Datum11
{       
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class MessegesOtvet
{         
    public List<Datum11> Data { get; set; }     
}
```

Десериализация

```
MessegesOtvet answer1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessegesOtvet>(answ);
```

Пробовал доставать через Max() как из массива и листа - не получилось

Comment: что именно не получилось?
десериализация проходит успешно? список объектов адекватный?
у всех объектов есть свойство Id? там есть циферка отличная от 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, должно помочь:

```
Data.Select(x => x.Id).Max();
```

Comment: Спасибо, действительно помогло)

Comment: @Teslaaaaa1 `Data.Max(x => x.Id);`